# The `box-sizing` issue of `input[type="button"]` in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Following is the example (I'm using Chrome & Safari);

```css
input[type="button"] {
  width: 33.333%;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
```

Here are **three buttons** and I want them to fill in **one row**, so I set `width: 33.333%` and `box-sizing:border-box` for the elements.

However, instead of staying in the right side of the first row, the third button appears in the second row somehow.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs are `display`ed as `inline-block` (per user-agent stylesheet). Therefore, *the line breaks between the inputs are rendered as spaces*. You end up with `3*33.33% + 2*space` width (which is more than 100% and the line breaks).

Either put them on a single line or use `display: block` explicitly (or a `display: flex` on the container).

```css
[type="button"] { width: calc(100% / 3); }
```

```html
<input type="button"><input type="button"><input type="button">

<hr>

<input type="button">
<input type="button">
<input type="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `float: left`.

```css
   input[type="button"] {
  width: 33.333%;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
<input type="button" value="Restore" />
```